# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'

Tags: pandas, csv, excepciones

El script siguiente, importa dentro de un Dataframe, cotizaciones de diversos valores descargados de la Web de un banco, a ficheros csv.
Sobre el Dataframe creado (df), no me permite aplicar funciones  de pandas, como por ejemplo, def.info(), df.describe(), etc.  El error que devuelve parece indicar que el df no es de ningún tipo. 
He visto algún otro post sobre este tipo de excepción pero no llego a deducir mi solución. ¿alguien me puede ayudar a entender por qué se lanza la excepción?, ¿cómo puedo resolverla?. Necesito que en el Dataframe las fechas sean del tipo DateTimeIndex y las cotizaciones del tipo non-null float64.
Para poder aplicar funciones como "pd.to_numeric", es necesario disponer de un Dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.display import display
""" Acepta un nombre de símbolo como una cadena y devuelve la ruta al archivo CSV correspondiente, 
asumiendo que se almacena en el directorio "./Ficheros_csv"."""
def symbol_to_path(symbol, base_dir="./Ficheros_csv"):
    """Return CSV file path given ticker symbol."""
    return os.path.join(base_dir, "{}.csv".format(str(symbol)))

def get_data(symbols, dates):
    """Read stock data (adjusted close) for given symbols from CSV files."""
    # Hacemos las fechas índices del df.
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    # añadir Iberdrola como referencia, si no existe en symbols, en la posición 0
    if 'iberdrola' not in symbols:  
        symbols.insert(0, 'iberdrola')

    for symbol in symbols:
        #Leer y unir las cotizaciones de cada símbolo
        # Usar la función  symbol_to_path   para conseguir los ficheros .csv
        df_temp = pd.read_csv("./Ficheros_csv/{}.csv".format(symbol),index_col = "Date",
                              decimal  =",", parse_dates = True, usecols = ["Date", "Close"], na_values = ["nan"], sep='\t')

        # rename the adjacent close column to the symbol name
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns = {"Close":symbol})

        # Añadir los datos del nuevo dataframe
        df = df.join(df_temp)  # por defecto how = "left" , con inner elimina filas con NaN       
        """ Elimina filas con NaN en las columnas incluidas en la lista """
        if symbol == 'iberdrola':   
            df = df.dropna(subset = ['iberdrola']) 
        df.dropna(axis=0, how = "any", inplace=True)
        #df.drop("iberdrola", 1, inplace = True)
    return df

def test_run():
    # Define a date range
    dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2018-12-31')

    # Selección de símbolos para leer de ficheros csv
    symbols = [ "Acatis_DE000A0X7541_r4", "Avantage_ES0112231008_r4",
               "DedaloPP_F1467_r4", "EPSV_EP2_r4","Nexus_ES0173268006_r4",
               "NexuxPP_F1605_r4", "TrueValue_ES0180792006_r4", "ValorRelativo_ES0128522002_r4" ]                

    #symbols = ["Eurostoxx_50", 'iberdrola','ibex_35','nasdaq', 'nikkei_225','renta_4',
               #'sp_500','SPY', 'telefonica']    

    # Get stock data
    df_R4 = get_data(symbols, dates)
    df_R4 = df_R4.rename(columns = {"iberdrola": "referencia", "Acatis_DE000A0X7541_r4": "Acatis", "Avantage_ES0112231008_r4": "Avantage",
                          "DedaloPP_F1467_r4": "DedaloPP","EPSV_EP2_r4": "EPSV",
                           "Nexus_ES0173268006_r4": "Nexus", "NexuxPP_F1605_r4": "NexusPP",
                          "TrueValue_ES0180792006_r4": "TrueValue","ValorRelativo_ES0128522002_r4": "ValorRelativo"})

    lista_nombres = ["Acatis", "Avantage", "DedaloPP", "EPSV", "Nexus", "NexusPP",
                     "TrueValue", "ValorRelativo"]

    df_R4 = df_R4.drop("referencia", 1)
    print (display(df_R4[:3]))

""" Asegura que el código que sigue a esta línea solo se ejecutará si usted
ejecute el script directamente, en lugar de importarlo para usarlo en otro programa (parte de su).
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df_R4 = test_run()
```

Este script nos presenta lo que parece un Dataframe, pero al ejecutar.

```
df_R4.info()
```

nos devuelve.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'
```

El script y los ficheros estab accesibles en 
https://github.com/akitxu/Aprendiendo-GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error significa literalmente que estás intentando acceder al método `.info()` del objeto `None`. Es decir, no es que tu dataframe no sea de ningún tipo, sino que no es realmente un dataframe, sino el objeto `None`.

¿Por qué sucede esto? Veamos cómo asignas ese objeto:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df_R4 = test_run()
```

Es decir, le asignas el valor devuelto por `test_run()`. Y ¿qué devuelve `test_run()`? Pues si examinas el código de esa función verás que no contiene ninguna instrucción `return`, así que no devuelve NADA. ¡Ya sabemos de dónde viene el `None`!

Basta por tanto añadir esta instrucción a `test_run()`:

```
         return df_R4
```

Comment: Efectivamente, Esa era la causa. Muchas gracias